# "Done recipes" vs "Tried recipes" in a heading

Tags: word-choice

I am making an simple app for listing and tracking recipes and wondering what might be the most natural heading for the already made recipes list.

The app works like that: The user can browse a recipes list and choose one for start cooking, and it is possible to mark a recipe as done, and in another screen she can see the "Done recipes" list.

Is there a best/most natural wording to this heading?

Comment: What's the exact context? Is it like [*Julie & Julia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julie_%26_Julia)? That's a dramatisation of young New Yorker Julie Powell spending a year working through 524 of chef Julia Child's recipes, so on any given day Julie had tried / done / cooked *some* of those recipes, but not others. Apart from "cook", there isn't really any obvious candidate English word for ***actually follow a recipe*** - and of course I'm quite sure that at least *some* of those recipes wouldn't actually involve any "cooking" at all (Waldorf salad, say, though I don't think that is one! :)

Comment: Perhaps you could make a pun out of it: "well done", "canned list" whatever.

Comment: Recipes tried or tested.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The context is very like the same, the user can browse a recipes list and choose one for start cooking, and it is possible to mark a recipe as done, and in another screen she can see the list mentioned in the question. I will update the question with this information. Thank you!

Comment: @WeatherVane It looks a very interesting idea! Gonna think about it! Thanks!

Comment: @Lambie So it have the same meaning reversing the words too? Or it is better?

Thank you so much you all for the comments!

Comment: Just because I don't think there ***is*** an English verb specifically suited to this context doesn't mean I agree with it being closed as POB. But you might reasonably try asking something like this on either SO "User Experience" (user i/f design) or "Seasoned Advice" (the cookery subsite).

Comment: ...but I think the best you're gonna get is already in your own comment - *it is possible to mark a recipe as **done***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for the insights! Didn't knew there was a specific "User Experience" SO, will check it out later! This discussion was enough for me to have a better understanding on the question, thanks! And yeah, this probably will be "Done recipes"! :)